# FORECAST / TREND with *really* simple data Excel - GSheets

Tags: excel

I'm tracking something extremely simple; a week number, and body weight.

I can't get Excel or Google Sheets to use either of those functions to predict what the weight will be for the next 4 weeks.

I have a chart like this

1 185

2 184.3

3 186

4 189

5 183

6 186

7 188

etc

I need a prediction of 8, 9, 10, 11.

I've tried =FORECAST(X57,Y53:Y56,X53:X56) where the x57 is the next week number, but what happens is Excel/sheets starts counting at a lower number than the last weight. I got a weird negative number with TREND. I know I'm not doing something right. I tried switching the ranges too.

I've inserted a screenshot from Sheets.

I feel really stupid because I should be able to figure this out but it's been over an hour of scratching my head and getting frustrated. I don't have Excel 2016 with the Forecast graph function.

Am I doing this right, but because the numbers go up and down this is Excel/Sheet's best guess?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

I placed your data in **G1** through **H7**:

[image]

2<sup>nd</sup> Order Polynomial Trendline

```
Equation: y = (A * x2) + (B * x ) + C
```

**A**  =INDEX(LINEST(y,x^{1,2}),1)
**B**  =INDEX(LINEST(y,x^{1,2}),1,2)
**C**  =INDEX(LINEST(y,x^{1,2}),1,3)

So in **I1** through **I3**, enter these equations for the coefficients **A**, **B** and **C**:

```
=INDEX(LINEST(H1:H7,G1:G7^{1,2}),1)
=INDEX(LINEST(H1:H7,G1:G7^{1,2}),1,2)
=INDEX(LINEST(H1:H7,G1:G7^{1,2}),1,3)
```

Then enter 8 through 11 in column **G**.  Then **H8** enter:

```
 =$I$1*G8^2+$I$2*G8+$I$3
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: @pnuts For **interpolation**, it does not matter.  For **extrapolation**, I get nervous.  I would try the second order first.  Only if it *looks* linear would I use a linear fit instead.

Comment: @pnuts In any case, this approach avoids using the `FORCAST()` function.

Comment: Having always had extreme difficulties with math in life I never got past basic math classes in school. This went way over my head. Very neat though. Thx

Answer (score 1):

I know you don't have Excel 2016, but here is how it would look if you insert a forecast from Excel's Data menu.

Select the cells and then click Data > Forecast Sheet. Change the Forecast End to 11. I left the Options at the defaults as displayed.

[image]

Next click Create and you will see the formulas for the forecast and the data in an Excel Table. You can inspect the FORECAST functions used, for example in column C:

```
=FORECAST.ETS(A9,$B$2:$B$8,$A$2:$A$8,1,1)
```

[image]

Comment: @yeah I missed that. But I decided to keep the answer just to show the results that Excel comes up with. Maybe it helps to see if the GSheets is right.

Comment: No, that's actually great because it shows that there are different paths it could predict. Thank you. I guess you could consider this solved because there's no real ideal answer?

Answer (score 1):

With the data in A1:B7 you could either chart that, set a trendline (linear seems reasonable) and pick up the formula from the chart:

```
=0.3357*(A1)+184.56
```

(in C1 and copied down for comparison) or apply this in B8 and copy down:

```
=FORECAST(A8,B$1:B$7,A$1:A$7)
```

The known points are used for the chart on the left and the known points plus [FORECAST](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/forecast-trend.html) ones for the chart on the right:

[image: SO45496623 example]

Comment: Where are you getting 0.3357? Also, I have some trendlines for other data and also in the weight bar graph, it does work there of course, but just wanted to see if there was a way to get actual numbers.

Comment: Ah, I was looking at GSheets...going "wth?"  :) :)